# Why do I have empty space between pictures on a panel when dragged and dropped?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, I am trying go drag and drop Picture Boxes on a panel which works but somehow there is empty space between the boxes and I do not understand why this happens?

Below by clicking on the picture you will be able to see an example of what is my situation and also the code behind which uses events on the panel and on the Image Box - DragDrop,DragOver and MouseDown.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvesA.png)

```
private void panelMap_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }

 private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!runningSimulation)
        {
            pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            dragTypeOne = true;
        }
    }` private void panelMap_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point cursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        Point drawPoint = new Point();

        //Finding out which cell the crossing is dropped on
        determineCell(e);
        drawPoint = map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Location;

        //Moving the crossing
        if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            foreach (Crossing cr in map.Crossings)
            {
                if (cr.Location == mouseDown && !map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Taken)
                {
                    cr.Location = drawPoint;
                    // cr.Pb_Background.Location = drawPoint;
                    cr.Pb_Transparent.Location = drawPoint;
                    map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Taken = true;
                    map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Crossing = map.Cells[firstSelection - 1].Crossing;
                    map.Cells[firstSelection - 1].Taken = false;
                    map.Cells[firstSelection - 1].Crossing = null;
                    //grid.CheckNeighbours(selectedCell - 1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < map.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (map.Cells[i].Taken)
                        {
                            map.CheckNeighbours(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Taken)
        {
            map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Taken = true;
            PictureBox pb_b = new PictureBox();
            pb_b.Height = panelMap.Height / 3;
            pb_b.Width = panelMap.Width / 4;
            pb_b.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb_b.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pb_b.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Down);
            pb_b.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

            //Added transparent layer
            PictureBox pb_t = new PictureBox();
            pb_t.Size = pb_b.Size;
            pb_t.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Down);

            //Which crossing will be dragged
            if (dragTypeOne)
            {
                System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
                Cross_Shaped cr = new Cross_Shaped(drawPoint, pb_b, pb_t);
                pb_b.Location = cr.Location;
                pb_b.Tag = cr;
                pb_t.Tag = cr;
                map.AddCrossing(cr);
                map.Cells[selectedCell - 1].Crossing = cr;

                pb_b.Image = CTF.Properties.Resources.crossing;
            }

            this.Controls.Add(pb_b);
            this.Controls.Add(pb_t);


            pb_t.BringToFront();


            pb_b.Location = drawPoint;

            pb_b.Parent = panelMap;
            pb_t.Parent = pb_b;
            map.CheckNeighbours(selectedCell - 1);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited it.